# Socket IO get all rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I'm currently trying to build a web chat app, kind of like omegle but with no video or voice. I'm trying to get all the rooms, but once I try console logging the rooms all I get is either

```
Map(2) {
  '7zqY9KBN2F9u8QKOAAAB' => Set(1) { '7zqY9KBN2F9u8QKOAAAB' },
  'test' => Set(1) { '7zqY9KBN2F9u8QKOAAAB' }
}
```

this is my code for trying to log the users

```
  //
  socket.on("chatroom with stranger", async msg => {
    console.log(msg)
    await socket.join("test")
    
    socket.emit("test", "Message to everyone")

    console.log(Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.sids))
    
  })
```